# __construct_runtime_integrity_test fails after upgrading to polkadot 0.9.38

Tags: error, testing

After upgrading our chain to polkadot version 0.9.38 and run `SKIP_WASM_BUILD= cargo test --all` I get  the following test error

```rs
'__construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests' panicked at 
'Builder finished with `build_or_panic`; 
The panic is expected if runtime weights are not correct: 
ValidationErrors { has_errors: true, errors: [
    "[DispatchClass::Normal] Weight { ref_time: 375000000000, proof_size: 0 } (total) has to be greater than Weight { ref_time: 381015000, proof_size: 0 } (base block) & Weight { ref_time: 99840000, proof_size: 0 } (base extrinsic)",
    "[DispatchClass::Normal] Some(Weight { ref_time: 349900160000, proof_size: 0 }) (max_extrinsic) must not be 0. Check base cost and average initialization cost.",
    "[DispatchClass::Normal] Weight { ref_time: 500000000000, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight { ref_time: 480855000, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)",
    "[DispatchClass::Operational] Weight { ref_time: 500000000000, proof_size: 0 } (total) has to be greater than Weight { ref_time: 381015000, proof_size: 0 } (base block) & Weight { ref_time: 99840000, proof_size: 0 } (base extrinsic)",
    "[DispatchClass::Operational] Some(Weight { ref_time: 474900160000, proof_size: 0 }) (max_extrinsic) must not be 0. Check base cost and average initialization cost.",
    "[DispatchClass::Operational] Weight { ref_time: 125000000000, proof_size: 0 } (reserved) has to be greater than Weight { ref_time: 99840000, proof_size: 0 } (base extrinsic) if set",
    "[DispatchClass::Operational] Weight { ref_time: 500000000000, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight { ref_time: 480855000, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)",
    "[DispatchClass::Mandatory] Weight { ref_time: 500000000000, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight { ref_time: 480855000, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)"
]}
```

I was running the tests for each pallet separately and they seems to pass as expected. Any guidance on how to resolve it

Link to code [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/runtime-upgrade/polkadot-v0.9.38)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your declaration of `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT` to:

```
pub const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT: Weight = Weight::from_parts(
    WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND.saturating_div(2),
    polkadot_primitives::MAX_POV_SIZE as u64,
);
```

In your code base you don't set the pov size and this will make the initialization of `RuntimeBlockWeights` fail.

Comment: Thanks! All works as expected after updating the MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT value