# Error: "Did not find the benchmarking metadata" after building runtime for benchmarking

Tags: benchmarking, error

After upgrading our chain to polkadot 0.9.38 I managed to build the benchmarking using `cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks`  but when I try to benchmark any pallet after the build I always get the following error

```
Builder finished with `build_or_panic`; The panic is expected if runtime weights are not correct:

Error: Input("Did not find the benchmarking metadata. This could mean that you either did not build the node correctly with the `--features runtime-benchmarks` flag, or the chain spec that you are using was not created by a node that was compiled with the flag:
```

Any guidance on how to fix that error?

Link to code [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/runtime-upgrade/polkadot-v0.9.38)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was coming from setting the `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT` value using `Weight::from_ref_time` instead of `Weight::from_parts` using `polkadot_primitives::MAX_POV_SIZE as u64` as proof size value

The correct value is

```
pub const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT: Weight = Weight::from_parts(
    WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND.saturating_div(2),
    polkadot_primitives::MAX_POV_SIZE as u64,
);
```

Found the solution to the problem through the answer of a question I asked [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8950/construct-runtime-integrity-test-fails-after-upgrading-to-polkadot-0-9-38)